# I'm using kubernetes dashboard but proxy is down

Tags: kubernetes

I’m using kubernetes dashboard.
I use only http to communicate.
Authentication is skipped.

However, the nohup watch kubectl proxy process is failing.
What should I do?

Proxy process crash occurs a short time after the command is executed.

```
■ process
nohup watch kubectl proxy --address='0.0.0.0' --accept-hosts='^*$' -n kubernetes-dashboard &

■ dashboard log
ubuntu@master:~$ kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-5c9968d778-phbks -n kubernetes-dashboard
2023/05/18 03:36:42 Using apiserver-host location: http://{ipv4 address}:{port number}
2023/05/18 03:36:42 Using namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
2023/05/18 03:36:42 Skipping in-cluster config
2023/05/18 03:36:42 Using random key for csrf signing
2023/05/18 03:36:42 Error while initializing connection to Kubernetes apiserver. This most likely means that the cluster is misconfigured (e.g., it has invalid apiserver certificates or service account's configuration) or the --apiserver-host param points to a server that does not exist. Reason: Get "http://{ipv4 address}:{port number}/version": dial tcp {ipv4 address}:{port number}: connect: connection refused
Refer to our FAQ and wiki pages for more information: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/FAQ

■ pod status
ubuntu@master:~$ kubectl get pod -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS         AGE
dashboard-metrics-scraper-8c47d4b5d-kcnm8   1/1     Running            0                3h
kubernetes-dashboard-5c9968d778-phbks       0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   18 (2m39s ago)   3h
```